# Objective C - call NSNumber outside FOR loop

Tags: objective-c

It seems that i didn't cover my basics enough, but I hope that You guys mabybe will be able to help here.

I need to use `cateringView.status` outside this loop and even in another class. This is simple BOOL value, parsed from XML with PUGIXML

```
- (void)dataPrepared
{
    Food* food = (Food*)[[DataManager sharedInstance] dataForItem:kDataManagerItemCatering];

    if (food)
    {
        for (CateringView* cateringView in cateringViews)
            [cateringView removeFromSuperview];

        [cateringViews removeAllObjects];

        for (FoodItem* item in food.catering)
        {
            CateringView* cateringView = [CateringView new];

            [cateringView.imageView loadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image] session:[DataManager sharedInstance].session completion:nil];

            cateringView.status = item.status;

            [self addSubview: cateringView];
            [cateringViews addObject: cateringView];
        }

        [self layoutSubviews];

    }

    [super dataPrepared];

}
```

Could You explain me how can I do that?

My header file:

(...)

```
@interface CateringView : UIView
@property (strong) NSNumber* status;
@end


@interface CateringPreviewCell : PreviewCell

{
    NSMutableArray* cateringViews;
```

(...)

```
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the issue ? Make CateringView* cateringView as a property and use it anywhere in your class.

Comment: I cannot use this desired variable anywhere outside the loop unfortunately.

Comment: Your first for loop doesn't have curly braces around it and makes the code look messy.  I can't say what's wrong without confirming that item.status is not nil.  You should instantiate cateringView outside of the for loop using [CateringView alloc] init] if you want to be able to use it outside of the for loop.

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all. There are many instances of CateringView.

Comment: Elko, there aren't many instances of CateringView.  There's the class CateringView, the array cateringViews, and the instance cateringView.  However, I have no reason to believe that food.catering is an array, and if that is the case, the for loop probably isn't executing.

Comment: @jungledev He explicitly asks how to access 'cateringView.status', and cateringView is a loop variable. If there are not more of them, there wouldn't be a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this somebody else's code you are trying to understand? It is unclear what you are asking, but you appear to be confusing the lifetime of *local variables* and *objects*. Maybe the following will help:

The second `for` loop starts:

```
    for (FoodItem* item in food.catering)
    {
        CateringView* cateringView = [CateringView new];
```

This last statements does two things:

1. The right hand side (RHS) creates a new *object* of type `CateringView`. The result of the RHS is a *reference* to the created object. The *lifetime* of the created object extends as long as there is a reference to it[A].
2. The left hand side (LHS) creates a new *local variable* called `cateringView`. The reference returned by the RHS is stored in this variable. The lifetime of the created variable is a *single iteration* of the `for` loop.

At the end of the loop the code is:

```
        [self addSubview: cateringView];
        [cateringViews addObject: cateringView];
    }
```

These two statements take the *reference*, to the created `CateringView` object, which is stored in the local variable `cateringView` and add it to this object's (which is an instance of the `CateringPreviewCell` class) subviews and `cateringViews` *instance variable*.

After these two statements have executed you have stored the reference to the created `CateringView` object *three* times: in the local variable `cateringView`, in the owning object's subviews, and in the owning object's `cateringViews` instance variable.

Also after these statements the loop iteration ends, so the lifetime of the local variable `cateringView` ends and you can no longer use that variable. However the reference to the object that was stored in that local variable still exists in two locations and that object is *still alive*.

You are stating you need to access `cateringView.status` outside of the loop. That does not make sense, the variable does not exist. However the object the variable referenced when it did exist is still alive, so the `status` value you seek is still around - you are just looking in the wrong place.

After the loop, and after the call to `dataPrepared` has returned, **all** the `CateringView` objects created can be accessed either:

- as subviews of the object instance of `CateringPreviewCell` that `dataPrepared` was called on, or
- as members of the instance variable `cateringViews` of that object instance.

The first of these is accessible "outside the class", the second can be provided you have instance methods defined on `CateringPreviewCell` which provided access to the instance variable.

HTH

---

[A]: This is not exactly true, but sufficient for the purpose here. Later you may learn about things such as *weak references* which do not govern how long an object lives.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't use `cateringView`, because you actually have many of them. They're all stored in `cateringViews` so that's what you'd actually use. You'd either iterate all the views in that array or you'd choose one at a specific index to interact with.

Comment: I can NSLog this cateringView.status on the beginning of whole class, but it's null because no item.status has been assigned to it.

Comment: which class? so you have an instance variable to store it, you just aren't storing it? which instance would you want to store?

Comment: `item.status` is assigned from XML, and it changes value of `cateringView.status`. I tried to NSLog this anywhere, but it was null.
I am aware of that this variable is destroyed outside the loop.

Comment: the item.status is not "destroyed" outside the loop, it just needs to be accessed on an individual level via ((FoodItem *)food.catering[indexDesired]).status

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing whether your *intention* is to try to add .status to

1. existing objects inside the `cateringViews` array

or

2. new objects that you add to `cateringViews` array

since your question has missing information and isn't very clear, here is the solution for #2

```
for (CateringView* cateringView in self.cateringViews) {  //needed curly braces and self. to access property var
    [cateringView removeFromSuperview];
}

[self.cateringViews removeAllObjects];  //again needed self.

for (int i = 0; i < food.catering.count; i++) { //make sure food.catering is array and not nil
    CateringView* cateringView = [[CateringView alloc] init];    
    [cateringView.imageView loadURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.image] 
                                                 session:[DataManager sharedInstance].session 
                                              completion:nil];
    FoodItem *item = food.catering[i]
    cateringView.status = item.status;

    [self addSubview: cateringView];
    [self.cateringViews addObject: cateringView];
}
```

If I'm wrong and you're trying to accomplish #1, (consider improving your question wording if this is the case) then you'll need to loop through `self.cateringViews` as well.